# Wordpress update "Another update is currently in progress."

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to update my Wordpress site to version 4.9.8, but when I go to update I receive the alert "Another update is currently in progress.".
I've already checked my database in the table **wp_options** but I don't see any **core_updater** record in the column **option_name**
I've tried already to disable all plugins and either to change set Twenty Seventeen such as theme.
Any ideas?

Moreover I don't if the things are linked, but when I try to upload a media, the file isn't uploaded and I see just a "No title" in the media

Comment: no core_updater.lock neither ?

Comment: No..... nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem creating a new website with Wordpress 4.9.8 and I moved all content from the old website to the new

Answer (score 0):

**WordPress 4.9**

For me, this problem occurred after migrating from another server and importing my database from this server. On the new imported database, some table properties weren't being copied. If you open all of the default WordPress tables, you'd find rows like the `ID` having no `AUTO_INCREMENT` property.

So what I did was to reset the WordPress database structure back to its original, like so:

1. Back up my current database
2. Delete all tables in current database
3. Import tables from a fresh WordPress install or another working
   WordPress site
4. Empty (Truncate) the imported tables
5. Edit my backed up `.sql` file by replacing all occurrences of
   `CREATE TABLE` with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` (to avoid errors
   when importing)
6. Import the edited `.sql` backup